# how to hide html tags without remove it in php form

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

im getting stuck when i save string with paragraph, and the html tags `<p></p>` and `<br></br>` is come to save into database, if i use `strip_tags()` the string is being RAW..
anyone can help me pleasee..
sorry for my poor english

Comment: That's what `strip_tags()` is meant to do... what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Save the original version in a secondary, hidden input?

Comment: So what do you want to save? The HTML or the text only? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: i just want to save the original text without html tags, its succes use string_tags, but when i show, the text being raw..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need to have exceptions for your tags you can do

```
strip_tags($string,"<p><br>");
```

this will remove all tags except p and br.

to escape a string you can use

```
mysql_real_escape_string($str);
```

or just

```
addslashes($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function takes a second argument:

> string **strip_tags** ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

If you specify which tags you want saved (e.g., `strip_tags($text, '<p><br>');`), it will not remove those tags.

Answer (score -2):

u can use [strip_tags();](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp)

and also possible to  use jq;
its very easy and efective,,
u can use

```
$('<p>').attr('disabled',"disabled"");
```

if u any help comment my link i ll tell u

Comment: who add negative to my answer is there any wrong in that tell me i can coorect it

Comment: Not my downvote, but I would guess that since A: You gave strip_tags() as an answer when OP said he was already using it. B: Suggested that jQuery or "jq" as you put it would be an acceptable solution, and especially since this is not a javascript question or even remotely related to jquery, and the fact that that piece of jQuery would do nothing useful anyways. C: No attempt at proper English. It's not "u", it's "you". I'm sure you know this.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: here not conduction grammatical class from my word whether u can able to get!!!thats matter

Comment: @K6t: I don't understand you, sorry. Grammar and spelling does make a difference, we're have to communicate with each other clearly. I know you understand that "u" is not a word, it's a letter, so don't be surprised in the future if you are downvoted for this alone.