# "br" tags shows in my text in the website?

Tags: html, css

I have problem with `<br />` tags. They show like a code in my site text, and don't make new line as they should!

I see the my texts like this in the site:

```
fasdkasdlksnad <br /> sadsadsadsd <br /> dsadsadsad<br />    
به نام خدا<br /> نماي مدرن <br /> مشاوره، طراحي و اجراي نماي ساختمان :<br />
```

I have used this code befor inserting to database:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($link,nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['text'])));
```

what should i do to solve this problem?
thankyou

Comment: Show a sample of actual HTML markup, as delivered to a browser and viewable in “View Source”. It seems that your code is changing “<” to “&lt;”, which causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($link,nl2br(strip_tags($_POST['text'])));
```

Comment: your edit just removed the br codes! i want they make new lines as they should

Comment: Visit following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911472/how-to-hide-html-tags-without-remove-it-in-php-form Hope, this would be helpful for you

Comment: thanks. but my problem is different! i want to have br codes but when i print them in my page they don't work as usual and i see <br /> tag instead! i need to have breaks not delete them!